# Far future expire header and HTTP 304

Tags: http

I'm trying to optimize the loading time of a website. One of the things I've done is set a far-futures expires header for static content so that they are cached (as described by [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires)). However, even though they are cached, the browser still sends a request and gets back a 304 (Not Modified) response for that resource.

I realize the 304 response is very small and probably has minimal performance effect, but is there a way to make it such that the browser will no longer send the request at all and just always use the cache for that resource?

Comment: Wouldn't that be up to the browser?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may want to try [turning off ETags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499966/etag-vs-header-expires) if you are sending both etags and expires.  Some people [suggest turning off eTags](http://mrclay.org/index.php/2009/03/03/you-probably-dont-need-etag/), especially if you have a load balancer.

Also, note, when you press reload on your page, Firefox WILL recheck all the resources. These will come back with 304's.  If you press shift-reload, it will re-request all the resources without etags. So don't use the refresh/reload button to test your last-modifed/etag settings.

Comment: Ah, that was my problem! I was using browser refresh to check if the access logs. When I access it using a normal link, the 304s are gone. Thanks!

Comment: I, too, failed with the browser refresh. Thank you for sharing this!