# PHP: Detect Page Refresh

Tags: php, refresh

I have a page `action.php` on which I run an SQL query through the code, so that whenever the page is viewed the query runs like **its like counting page views**

```
<?php
mysqli_query("UPDATE ****");
?>
```

The problem is when the page is refreshed, the query is run & PAGE REFRESH is counted as a PAGE VIEW which I want to avoid.

**Question:** How to avoid it ?

What I am looking for is a simple solution so that I can check

```
if( page was refresh ) //some condition
{
 do
}
```

Comment: is there any $_SERVER[''] attribute which would be different when a page is directed from a link & the page is refreshed.. if that is so then there is no problem solving this

Comment: @Junaid Saeed: just to be clear, do you also wish to not count when a user browses away from the page and then browses back?

Comment: There is no change in $_SERVER array for page refresh so, May be done by Using Session

Comment: no.. if i wanted to do that i would store some user identity with me and count the distinct identities...

Comment: thinking over it has made me realize this shouldn't be handled by PHP...

Comment: `@everybody :` i have posted the solution of this as answer to my own question.. look below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have solved the problem ... HURRAHHH with no session & no cookies

the solution is a combination of PHP : AJAX : JavaScript

the query that you want to run on Page Load & not on page Refresh run it as via AJAX call lets say my function for doing that is

```
function runQUERY()
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST","doIT.php",false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and i can simply check with Javascript that the page is a fresh load or its a refresh by doing the following

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkRefresh()
{
    if( document.refreshForm.visited.value == "" )
    {           
        // This is a fresh page load
            alert ( 'Fresh Load' );
        document.refreshForm.visited.value = "1";
            ..call you AJAX function here
    }
    else
    {
        // This is a page refresh
        alert ( 'Page has been Refreshed, The AJAX call was not made');

    }
}
</script>    
</head>

<body onLoad="checkRefresh()">

<form name="refreshForm">
<input type="hidden" name="visited" value="" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and in your **doIT.php** simple add your PHP code which you were going to put in the normal page

```
<?php
mysql_query("UPDATE---------");
//put any code here, i won't run on any page refresh
?>
```

Comment: This assumes that the form values are retained after a refresh -- this is true in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome.

Comment: well then i think its Google's problem to match the steps while walking... and not going on doing a catwalk.. thinking `oh i can do this because now i am very special`

Comment: I don't think this behavior you're seeing in FF and IE is part of any standard, and it could be subject to change, inconsistent between versions of those browsers, non-future-proof, etc. Cookie seems like a far more reliable solution.

Comment: Indeed, Chrome is not doing anything wrong, because there's no specified behavior for retaining form values on page refreshes/back/forward navigation. The *correct* way would be to present the page as intended (usually blank); retaining form values is something that some browsers may or may not do. Very interesting hack that works at least partly though.

Comment: Looks like this does not work when javascript is not enabled.

Comment: The answer by the questionnaire is wrong and is misleading to the SO users.

Comment: You may never trust client side code. Your js and ajax code runs at client side.

Comment: client side code can easily be manipulated so its not 100% perfect

Answer (score 40):

I found this snippet [here](http://www.yourhowto.net/detect-page-refresh-php/), and it worked perfectly for me:

```
$pageWasRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';

if($pageWasRefreshed ) {
   //do something because page was refreshed;
} else {
   //do nothing;
}
```

Comment: A POST request cant get "refreshed". It can only be send again. Thus chrome does this the right way and does not send the equivalent cache headers. @user1032531

Answer (score 18):

Best way to Detect Page Refresh. or Not ?(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>,<kbd>F5</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
$pageRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) &&($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0' ||  $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] == 'no-cache'); 
if($pageRefreshed == 1){
    echo "Yes page Refreshed";
}else{
    //enter code here
    echo "No";
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me using PHP 7.4.12 CGI server local dev machine, and Google Chrome Nov-2020

Answer (score 11):

You can't directly detect a page refresh, but you can use a cookie to simulate what you want:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['action'])) {
  // action already done
} else {
  setcookie('action');
  // run query
}
```

Depending on your requirements, you also need to decide when to remove the cookie and/or perform the action again.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to run it once for a user, I would set a session cookie and then use an if() statement.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!$_SESSION['loaded'])
{
    // insert query here
}

$_SESSION['loaded'] = true;

?>
```

Comment: once the $_SESSION['loaded'] is set i won't be able to make this check on any other page or on the same page with different parameters like you have the leech pages...unless the session is destroyed and i i destroy the session it means if my user is logged in, he\she will be logged out...  and this syntax that you have given above will not work.... correct syntax is 

<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['load']) )
{
    echo ("Go");
}
$_SESSION['load'] = 1;
?>

Comment: i have solved it , i have posted the solution of this as answer to my own question..

Answer (score 3):

```
    //here you get the url behind the domain.
    $currentPage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 

    //if the session current page is not set.
    if(!isset($_SESSION['currentPage'])){ 

      //set the session to the current page.
      $_SESSION['currentPage'] = $currentPage;     
    }

    //check if the session is not equal to the current page
    if($_SESSION['currentPage'] != $currentPage){

       // if it's not equal you set the session again to the current page.
       $_SESSION['currentPage'] = $currentPage;

       //set the query you want to use
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This can work in your scenario:

```
if(isset($_GET["token"])) {
    $view_token = $_GET["token"];
} else {
    $new_views = $views + 1;
    // UPDATE VIEWS
    $view_token = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5)), 0, 5);
    header("Location: ?token=$view_token");
}
```

If the user has a token in the URL, the view count will not update. Therefore, if the user tries to refresh, it will not update the view count. When the user does not have a token in the URL, the view count updates and refreshes the page WITH  a token. It is thinking outside of the box but it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can save a cookie that will be associated with the present page and if any link is clicked, update the cookie with the new page name. 
Assuming the above is done in **Javascript**, you can send this updateCookie information to the server to notify about a new page hit.

Or another approach could be, you can specify a **HTTP HEADER** that specifies after how much time the **cache expires** on a page and that way, the browser wont even send you a request about **page load/refresh**.

See http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#IMP-SCRIPT for information about CACHING

Also , check out Etag vs Expires in HTTP - [ETag vs Header Expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499966/etag-vs-header-expires/500103#500103)

Comment: Agreed on the cookie, but when expressly *refreshing* a page, a browser will usually request the page from the server again regardless of cache settings.

Answer (score -1):

```
if( $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] == 'max-age=0')
{
    $_SESSION['status'] = null;<br>
}
```