# Page Reload Detection in PHP is working in Xampp but not in Apache2.2.22

Tags: php, apache, session, xampp

I have been trying to detect the page reload/refresh in php using both Xampp and Apache 2.2.22 using PHP. It workd fine in Xampp but not using Apache 2.2.22( on my UNIX environment)

```
<?php
// Start the session
    session_start();
    $RequestSignature = md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].print_r($_POST, true));

    if (isset ($_SESSION['LastRequest']) && $_SESSION['LastRequest'] == $RequestSignature)
    {
          echo 'This is a refresh.';
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little ? It's kind of confusing because `xampp` uses apache server.

Comment: Yes. It uses Apache Server. So when I execute the above code using Xampp as my Apache Server, it works fine. But when I try to use Apache server (Apache 2.2.22) in my UNIX environment, it does not work

Comment: Xampp comes with some predefined settings which might be the stuff you should look into.

But I'd love to know what are you trying to create which you're doing these ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Detect Page Refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290230/php-detect-page-refresh)

Answer (score 1):

try dis

```
$pageWasRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';

if($pageWasRefreshed ) {
   //do something because page was refreshed;
} else {
   //do nothing;
}
```

Comment: at least change the variables and comments from where you are copying.

Comment: does it matter...just wanted to help the stuck mate.

Comment: Hey Thanks. It workd fine when the page is refreshed, But not when the page loads.

Comment: are you talking for first time page loading?