# change url if browser refreshed node

Tags: javascript, node.js, refresh

I have a node app. Let's say the url is like this:

`http://www.testurl.com/?access_token=1234`. This url gets generated by Spotify as this `access_toke`n is required to use their API.

Only if the user refreshes the page I want the url to remove the last part of the url and just load `http://www.testurl.com`. It is important that it only happens on page refresh, so that the user has to authenticate themselves again.

[I have tried these js solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript), but none of them work. I think they didn't work for the original poster also as there was no accepted answer.

I have seen that it is possible to [detect browser refresh using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290230/php-detect-page-refresh). Does anyone know if it is possible to detect the equivalent using `node`?

The php solution looks like this

```
$pageWasRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';
```

I have also tried the following, that didn't work either.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event){
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you instead just remove it from the url on page load, so that on page refresh it's gone?

```
history.replaceState(null, '', location.pathname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that's the best way to solve whatever it is you're trying to do but those HTTP headers can be checked for inside Node by accessing `request.headers` object. Here's a sample code:

```js
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
 res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'text/html'
 });

 // Home controller
 if(url.parse(req.url).path === "/") {

  if(req.headers["cache-control"] && req.headers["cache-control"] === "max-age=0") {
   console.log("User refreshed");
  } else {
   console.log("User did not refresh");
  }

  res.end("<h1>Hello there!</h1>");
 } else {
  res.statsCode = 404;
  res.end("Not found");
 }

}).listen(3000);
```