# How to force the browser to re-download the new version of a swf file?

Tags: apache, flash, browser-cache

I updated the `flash library XML/SWF (chart library)` to the latest version on my web application but the users still see the charts with the old library which is saved in there browser cache.

How can I force the browsers of my users to download the latest version of the SWF files.

I can't add a parameter at the end of the SWF file like : `charts.swf?v=1234.`

If I do that I get an error because the chart library load dynamically other SWF files of the library. The `charts.swf file` will be the new version but the other files will still be from the older version and I will get an error...

Can I do something with Apache or the header?

Comment: Would you consider to rename charts.swf to like charts_new.swf ?

Comment: @ajreal - I am not able to do that because I would have the same issue than using charts.swf?v=1234 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do that. Or you can change the directory which hold different version in different directory
.

.../v1/chart.swf

.../v2/chart.swf

Comment: @benjisail: Can you elaborate how did you solve this problem? I'm interested in a detailed answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Try Apache's [Expires Headers](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-expires.html#m0-askapache0):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(swf)$">
 ExpiresActive on
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 hours"
</FilesMatch>
```

and see this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499966/etag-vs-header-expires).