# How to remove Cache-control header no-cache

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, graphql, apollo

My team and I are working on a Laravel API which communicates with a Vue.js frontend that uses the Apollo client to consume the GraphQL responses.

We have an issue with cache-control headers being added to the response.

Apollo cannot cache the contents because the response contains this header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
```

In php.ini, we have this to disable sending cache-control headers by PHP:

```
; Set to {nocache,private,public,} to determine HTTP caching aspects
; or leave this empty to avoid sending anti-caching headers.
; http://php.net/session.cache-limiter
session.cache_limiter =
```

In the nginx config we cannot find anything that is setting those headers. I checked the global nginx.conf and config file we setup in sites/available.

I can add this to the nginx config, but it will only add another header:

```
add_header Cache-Control "public";

Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Cache-Control: public
```

If this header is not coming from PHP or nginx, then where could it be coming from? 
And how can I remove or overwrite it?

- Laravel 5.5
- Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql
- PHP 7.1
- nginx 1.14.0
- Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Try uploading a sample HTML and load it in browser & check the cache headers are present in it or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in any middleware you can use this example

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        return $response instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
            ? $response->header('pragma', 'no-cache')
                ->header('Cache-Control', 'no-store,no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0')
                ->header('X-ANY-HEADER', 'any header value')
            : $response;
    }
```

but i do not know this fix your problem

Comment: Yes, with $response->header('Cache-Control','public') it changes the no-cache header. So it was either Laravel adding this header, or the laravel-graphql package.

Comment: In addition, use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
 - and an example:

        $contents = View::make('index')->with([]));
        $response = Response::make($contents, 200);
        $response->header('Cache-Control','private');
        return $response;

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel, the `Cache-Control: no-cache, private` header is set in the vendor package Symfony http-foundation by the following logic:

```php
    /**
     * Returns the calculated value of the cache-control header.
     *
     * This considers several other headers and calculates or modifies the
     * cache-control header to a sensible, conservative value.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function computeCacheControlValue()
    {
        if (!$this->cacheControl) {
            if ($this->has('Last-Modified') || $this->has('Expires')) {
                return 'private, must-revalidate'; // allows for heuristic expiration (RFC 7234 Section 4.2.2) in the case of "Last-Modified"
            }

            // conservative by default
            return 'no-cache, private';
        }

        $header = $this->getCacheControlHeader();
        if (isset($this->cacheControl['public']) || isset($this->cacheControl['private'])) {
            return $header;
        }

        // public if s-maxage is defined, private otherwise
        if (!isset($this->cacheControl['s-maxage'])) {
            return $header.', private';
        }

        return $header;
    }
```

*Source: Laravel 5.6 `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ResponseHeaderBag.php` lines 269-299*

As the OP stated in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50745327/how-to-remove-cache-control-header-no-cache/50745545#comment-88499593) to @[the_hasanov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50745327/how-to-remove-cache-control-header-no-cache/50745545#answer-50745545), the header can be overwritten by implementing a middleware.

1. `php artisan make:middleware CachePolicy`
2. edit the new `app/Http/Middleware/Cachepolicy.php` so that it reads:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CachePolicy
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      // return $next($request);
      $response= $next($request);
      return $response->header('Cache-Control','no-cache, public');
    }
}
```

3. Modify `app/http/Kernel.php` to include the new middleware:

```php
...
protected $middleware = [
   ...
   \App\Http\Middleware\CachePolicy::class,
  ];
...
```

Comment: finally a solution after hours of search

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by Adding in your .htaccess if you are using apache

```
Header always set Cache-Control "no-cache, public"
```

so it will remove the Cache-Control:private 
and give the header response as

```
Cache-Control:no-cache , public
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `no cache` does NOT mean "**don't cache**", which is `no-store`, `no cache` "allows caches to store a response but requires them to **revalidate** it before reuse."  Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control for detailed information.

To revalidate, your server response should have `etag` or `Last-Modified`. Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching for detailed information. For example, at the section starts with "Validation is done by using a **conditional request** that includes an `If-Modified-Since` or `If-None-Match` request header." So your server probably don't have those fields for revalidation.

The `private` means "cache that exists in the client. It is also called local cache or browser cache. It can store and reuse personalized content for a single user."

@Vardkin's answer correctly pointed out it is in [computeCacheControlValue()](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/6.1/ResponseHeaderBag.php#L259)  that set those fields,

```
    if (!$this->cacheControl) {
        if ($this->has('Last-Modified') || $this->has('Expires')) {
            return 'private, must-revalidate'; // allows for heuristic expiration (RFC 7234 Section 4.2.2) in the case of "Last-Modified"
        }

        // conservative by default
        return 'no-cache, private';
    }
```

I want to add that `must-revalidate` also explained in those articles I attached.

1. in [Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

> HTTP allows caches to reuse **stale** responses when they are disconnected
> from the origin server. must-revalidate is a way to prevent this from
> happening

2. in [HTTP caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#freshness)

> Stale responses are not immediately discarded. HTTP has a mechanism to
> transform a stale response into a fresh one by asking the origin
> server...Validation is done by using a conditional request

But I never figure how much difference between `no-cache` & `must-revalidate` since they all need to validate.

One answer here [Which one to use : Expire Header, Last Modified Header or ETags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321876/which-one-to-use-expire-header-last-modified-header-or-etags) said "The difference between `ETag` and `Last-Modified` stamps is more semantic.", which may give some clue but again if both `no-cache` & `must-revalidate` need to validate what is the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

In the .htaccess file add the following code

```
    Header always set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
```

You can set any policy you wish but the important point to remember is to have "**Header always set**".