# Use ActiveX XMLHTTP with more xml

Tags: php, xml, ajax, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

Hi all I have a site develop in codeigniter.
In this site I have to make requests to 10 server with this code for example in javascript:

```
var XML_req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
XML_req.open("POST", link_server, false);
XML_req.send(unsescape(XMLdata));
```

I make a request and the result return me on var_XML_req.responseText
The problem is that:
The xml the xml response can have thousand of nodes, and I have to make the same request 10 times one for each server. I have 10 requests(the same for all server) and 10 response in single big xml.

I know that this requests are asynchronous but in this case I don't know if exist a method to handle this request and this big response, because multiple user can make request at the same time. I have a server with good features but I don't know if this requests and the big responses can be very slow.
Exist a method to handle this? 
I have thinked to make a cronjob ebery hour for every server and stor into a database but in this case I don't have real time data  I have to buy a very big database because I can have milion of data in many table.

I don't have many experience with this kind of work with a lot and a lot of data.
I hope that someone can explain me the right, the best and the more fast way to handle this request and response.

Comment: Ideally the API (which returns the XML) would be such that the server only returns the pertinent information in a minimum number of requests .. anyway, "millions of rows" isn't very much for a database and shouldn't be reason to avoid a cached approach outright. Of course, if just caching, the filesystem can be just as useful ..

Comment: Ok but inside every server are milions of record and sum each other i have to handle a lot of data. Caching data i don't know how Is possibile because i want real time data

Comment: @pst each node can contain a lot of information like 100 hotel every hotel have 1000 rooms this rooms have many data i can have a lot of data insidie every xml

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, if you are returning millions of rows in a single request something is wrong. Your queries should be small and should be returning only the bits of information people are looking for, not the full set:

[Dealing with Large Data in Ajax](http://css.dzone.com/articles/dealing-large-data-ajax)

There is always the option to use local storage in the browser:

[jQuery Ajax LocalStorage](https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-ajax-localstorage-cache)

Here is another answer that may provide some insight, too:

[LocalStorage, several Ajax requests or huge Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086773/localstorage-several-ajax-requests-or-huge-ajax-request)

Good luck!

Comment: The query is logic that I have to retrieve many data because I have to select for example all details of all rooms of the hotel of New York. Is a very big project and is normal to have milion of data.. sorry but your answer isn't what I want I want a solution to handle this data, I know how to storage data with ajax

Comment: My comment is TOTALLY pertinent, and having a browser handle millions of records is ... shortsighted. People are not using computers that have the horsepower to do what you're proposing. You probably do know about all the options, but you don't want to admit that you have to do it a different way.

Comment: no is impossible to do in a different way. Isn't a site for all user but for travel agency that want to retrieve all data together

Comment: Same principle applies to the travel agency. You don't have to return ALL the data, only the pieces that are VISIBLE.

Comment: sure but you understand that means a lot of data?? Because if you want to see a list of all camera available of all hotel of new york you can have big data.. i know that I have to select all data but this query is made by the provider I send an xml with a query and the provider return me the response standard I can't select only the data that I want only do a better filter

Comment: Okay, so now the question becomes, are you making a request directly to a third party with Ajax? Or you mean you're making this request through CodeIgniter, and using CodeIgniter's models/views to get the data? Is there any way to cache these requests (Server-side in a DB or a simple cache file)? Help me understand your needs. I think you have an architectural hurdle to overcome with the amount of data you are parsing and sending to the client, and there needs to be some caching somewhere in the middle.

Comment: Also, I don't appreciate the downvote since it wasn't a "wrong" answer, it wasn't the one you were looking for.

Comment: My request is to for example 10 provider and they return me the data for this reason i have a lot of data and i want to manage well this data

Comment: It does not preclude a caching solution, whether you have 1, 10, or 1000 providers.

Comment: I can't use so much cache beacuse i need to have real time data, for example the number of rooms available, this data change every minute

Comment: Then, I think this is a problem with the provider of the API, and not something you will be able to solve unless you do some XML parsing before the the data gets to the view. In that line of thought, XSLT may be an option here. Have you worked with XSLT?