# 304 Status code for my Azure CDN images hosted in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: cdn, azure-storage, http-status-codes

My images are stored in azure blob storage and referenced through my web application using my azure CDN. However all images return a 304 response header. Ideally I dont want the browser to return to the CDN to check for validity at every request, instead for the browser to always use the cache. - Well for at the life of the image cache.

With my limited knowledge of Caching, I understand that the cache uses the ETag value to compare if the version of the image is the same when requested. In this case it is and the CDN returns a 304 response. But because the CacheControl header is set as public, max-age=2592000 I would hope the browser would use the cached copy of the image. I have another CDN setup that has a hosted service endpoint which returns a 200 response because I remove the ETag value.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Few questions.  Did you mean 'max-age' instead of 'max-set'?  Is an Expires header also in the response?  What browser are we talking about here?

Comment: did mean max-age. Expires header isnt in the response and im working with firebug in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

When `ETag` "triggers" `304` response => the browser has sent `If-None-Match` validating request to the server. This is normally done after `max-age` has elapsed. You could find a good description of this here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/500103/2550808

it is also worth mentioning, Firefox browser settings should be set to default: go to `about:config` page and check this settings: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.check_doc_frequency

Going back to your question, something might be wrong with Cache-Control header the server returns to the browser. In my modest personal experience I didn't encounter explicitly `public` version of the header, it would be more likely just this:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
```

Anyway, here is pretty good description of headers pertaining to caching:

https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Alternatively, there might be other reasons for incessant re-validation to consider:

- VARY headers in server's 200 response with the file may affect caching;
- JavaScript calling reload on the location object, passing TRUE for bReloadSource;