# AFNetworking - Requests with ETag

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I am trying to do a request on a server, which responds with an Etag for cache purposes. I have written the following code for it, but the response for these calls is random most of the time i.e. sometimes response status code is 200 and some times 304(expected). Am I doing something wrong in my code or is there something specific with AFNetworking that I should keep in mind.!

```
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNzI0NTY5NzQwMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTQyNTA5OA@@._V1._SY90_.jpg"];
  NSMutableURLRequest *aRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [aRequest setValue:@"\"61-smtLpBSL_SY90_#1\"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"If-None-Match"];
  NSLog(@"headers: %@", aRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields);
  AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:aRequest imageProcessingBlock:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    NSLog(@"%@ %d", response.allHeaderFields, response.statusCode);
  } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Request failed with error: %@", error);    
  }];
  [operation start];
```

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I managed to fix this by changing my request to

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                               cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                           timeoutInterval:60];
```

Comment: That cachePolicy is not implemented.
enum {
    NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy = 0,

    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData = 1,
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData = 4, // Unimplemented
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,

    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad = 2,
    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad = 3,

    NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData = 5, // Unimplemented
};
typedef NSUInteger NSURLRequestCachePolicy;

Comment: Thanks, the cache policy was the issue. Whatever the default policy is caused my etag to be ignored.

Comment: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData  is OK, too

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and I receive status 200 - OK which is like it should be.

Code 304 - Not modified, I wasn't able to get. I have tried running command several times fast and slow but I always get 200 as a response.

Do you have more details when exactly it happens that you get 304 as response code?

304 response code generally means that the content hasn't been modified and you should get original request that had 200 as a response included in it.

Here you can read a bit more about Etag: [ETag vs Header Expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499966/etag-vs-header-expires)

Comment: That is what i am facing, a random 304. I am still not sure why would i get a 200 when I am sending the correct Etag in the request.! The more confusing thing is that the code works perfectly on wiki urls like: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/27/AScannerDarkly%281stEd%29.jpg  Reference: [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: Also, the server team i am working with has implemented only Etag. They don't send a HTTP-date for resource creation, so can't use Expires header..

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with the Etag logic and AFNetworking. My problem was just the `cachePolicy` not correctly set...

```
    var manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    manager.requestSerializer = AFHTTPRequestSerializer()
    manager.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    manager.requestSerializer.setValue(etag, forHTTPHeaderField: "If-None-Match")
    manager.GET(fullPath, parameters: parameters, success: {}, failure: {}))
```

I hope it will help someone !