# MVC's HTTP Caching - Last-Modified response header always equals Date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-headers, expires-header

I'm not fully understanding how .NET MVC's HTTP caching works because it doesn't seem like it's actually retrieving cached resource files.  I'm thinking I need to add some additional code somewhere...

First, let's take a look at how I've set up HTTP caching on static content (ie. images).  In my web.config, I have the following:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

This results in the images in my application to appear to be caching properly.  When I look at the response headers for an image, I see this (removed unnecessary headers):

```
    Date:Thu, 27 Feb 2014 16:27:48 GMT
    ETag:"086f8d199a4ce1:0"
    Expires:Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT
    Last-Modified:Thu, 29 Aug 2013 09:26:20 GMT
```

I'm seeing an ETag value which is good and my Expires is what it should be.  Additionally, the Last-Modified date is in the past.  I understand the Last-Modified date to be the date the server was last asked for that file.

Now let's look at the response headers for a javascript file that has been optimized by MVC.  As a reminder, [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) article states that "*Bundles set the HTTP Expires Header one year from when the bundle is created.*"

```
    Cache-Control:public
    Date:Thu, 27 Feb 2014 16:44:16 GMT
    Expires:Fri, 27 Feb 2015 16:44:16 GMT
    Last-Modified:Thu, 27 Feb 2014 16:44:16 GMT
    Vary:User-Agent
```

The Response Headers for the MVC cached file is missing the ETag for one.  There is a Cache-Control value of "public" which wasn't present on the static content response header.  Lastly, the Expires is 1 year after the Last-Modified date which is correct, but the Last-Modified date is always the same as the Date value.  These response headers to me seem like what they'd be when a resource is requested from the server for the first time and cached, not when it's been subsequently requested and retrieved from cache.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

**UPDATE**:  It actually seems to be caching in IE.  The Last-Modified date on subsequent requests remains a value in the past.  I'm not seeing this in FF or Chrome, though.  I confirmed that in both of those browsers, I haven't disabled caching.  What gives?

Comment: are you behind a proxy or filtering interceptor of any kind? i came across this question while debugging an issue that has many of the same symptoms and determined it was a corporate proxy withholding updates to the bundles

Comment: @meklarian: Thanks for chiming in.  When I logged this, I was indeed likely behind a company proxy!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache` is for static resources (files) only. So it works if you directly access pictures.

A bundle is a dynamic resource (a handler is generating the content). That is why the configuration directive does not apply.

---

Secondly, using `ETag`, `Expires`, `Last-Modified` are three different caching techniques. You should not use both techniques together as they work in a different way.

`Expires` tells the browser to keep the file in cache until a specified date. **The browser will never call the server** until that date.

`ETag` is a dynamic cache mechanism. **The browser will always call the server** but the server may not respond with the content if it has not changed.

`Last-Modified` is an ancient dynamic cache mechanism. It work the same way as `ETag` but is has a problematic requirement of exposing the correct modification date. Which is not a easy thing to find when creating dynamic content.

I think that combining multiple techniques should be reserved for well thought cases only. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/500103/282105) for details.

You may want to read the basics: [HTTP caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)

---

And then for your issue, I am not sure why so many header are exposed by your app. The presence of `Last-Modified` on a bundle is strange to explain. A bundle is a *virtual thing* that exposes various files combined as one. So it has no real *date of last modification*. Are you using extra caching code/modules?